# Jquery script firing each time scroll position changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

This code is designed to make a box shrink, before changing text, with a fadein/out effect. The only problem is, it always fires when the scroll position changes. For instance, say the scroll position was 100px, and then the user scrolls down once more, you'd see the text (inside of `li.um`) fade in then out. Is there a way to stop the code from running all the time, and only when the scroll position changes from >60 to <60 and vice versa?
Code + fiddle:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 60) {
        $("li.um").fadeOut(200);
        $("ul.undermenu").stop(true, false).animate({width:'160px'}, { duration: 500, queue: true});
        $("ul.undermenu").animate({height:'60px'}, { duration: 200, queue: true});
        window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('li.um').html('12345678901 pete@rufusmusic.co.uk');
        }, 700);
        $("li.um").fadeIn(200);
     }

     else {
         $("li.um").fadeOut(200);
         $("ul.undermenu").stop(true, false).animate({height:'30px'}, { duration: 200, queue: true});
         $("ul.undermenu").animate({width:viewportWidth}, { duration: 500,  queue: true});
         window.setTimeout(function () {
         $('li.um').html('Email: pete@rufusmusic.co.uk | Call: 12345678901 | Call: 01290923876');
         }, 700);
         $("li.um").fadeIn(200);
     }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2c8hmqdu/) (scroll down a few times to see what I mean about the text fading in/out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of where you were previously, so you know if you should trigger it or not. Here is a possible implementation using your existing code:

```
var previousScrollTop = 0;
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width(),
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 60) {
       if(previousScrollTop <= 60) {
            $("li.um").fadeOut(200);
            $("ul.undermenu").stop(true, false).animate({width:'160px'}, { duration: 500, queue: true});
            $("ul.undermenu").animate({height:'60px'}, { duration: 200, queue: true});
            window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('li.um').html('12345678901 pete@rufusmusic.co.uk');
            }, 700);
            $("li.um").fadeIn(200);
        }
     } else if (previousScrollTop > 60) {
        $("li.um").fadeOut(200);
        $("ul.undermenu").stop(true, false).animate({height:'30px'}, { duration: 200, queue: true});
        $("ul.undermenu").animate({width:viewportWidth}, { duration: 500,  queue: true});
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('li.um').html('Email: pete@rufusmusic.co.uk | Call: 12345678901 | Call: 01290923876');
          }, 700);
        $("li.um").fadeIn(200);
     }
     previousScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here to save your day again ^^
What you can do is create a throttle/debounce wrapper function that listens to unique custom event. Something like this:

```
/**
 * @description delay events with the same id, good for window resize events, keystroke, etc ...
 * @param {Function} func : callback function to be run when done
 * @param {Integer} wait : integer in milliseconds
 * @param {String} id : unique event id
 */
var delayedEvent = (function () {
    var timers = {};

    return function (func, wait, id) {
        wait = wait || 200;
        id = id || 'anonymous';

        if (timers[id]) {
            clearTimeout(timers[id]);
        }

        timers[id] = setTimeout(func, wait);
    };
})();
```

You can then use it like so:

```
delayedEvent(function(){/*your logic here*/}, 500, 'my scroll event');
```

**[See a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/8x66crak/)**

Comment: Ahh, Tim, so wonderful you're here! Haha. Sadly though, this working demo isn't.. working! ^^

Comment: Let me rephrase that, it works, however after I stopped scrolling, it still does the fadey thing again, which I only really want it to do when the text changes